# Why should the bulk modulus of a perfectly rigid body be infinite?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, elasticity, stress-strain

Also, what can we say about the Young's modulus and Shear Modulus of a perfectly rigid body and why?

Comment: Can you please tell me what do you understand by a rigid body?

Comment: A rigid body cannot change its shape and distribution of mass. I do not know any formal definition sadly.

Comment: Try a reading of Wikipedia article on rigid body (just first few lines).

Comment: Well the bulk modulus is just $$ E_v = \frac{stress}{strain}$$ and as you have said that distance between two points doesn’t change that means strain is zero and anything divided by zero is infinite. Therefore bulk modulus is infinite.

Comment: "The distance between any two given points on a rigid body remains constant in time regardless of external forces exerted on it." Okay this line answers the question, and there is also a semi-formal derivation given by @VK_fan. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bulk modulus is defined as $$B=-V\frac{P}{\Delta V}$$
It is obvious that we can't change the volume of an ideal rigid body so $\Delta V$ tends to zero hence magnitude of bulk modulus tends to $\infty$